# PHP associative array how read data

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have code, where i give date to my controller, and now i have big problem:

```
<td align="center">
    <input class="film_do_usuniecia" title="usuń" type="checkbox" name="film[usun][<?= $sVideo['2'] ?>][<?= $sVideo['3'] ?>]" />
</td>
```

I take my array with Post:

```
 $aKatalogi = $this->oRequest->getPostParam('film');


 if (is_array($aKatalogi['usun'])) {
     foreach ($aKatalogi['usun'] as $iKlucz => $sValue) {
         if (Tools::IsString($iKlucz, false) && $sValue == 'on') {
             $ftpconnection_video->f_delete_rs($iKlucz);
         }
      }
 }
```

And now is the problem:

How i can get this param: `[<?= $sVideo['3']`. In this param I have information about file: image or video.

I must checking it becouse if it image I delete it:

```
$ftpconnection_image->f_delete_rs($iKlucz);
```

If it is video:

```
$ftpconnection_video->f_delete_rs($iKlucz);
```

`$iKlucz` is a path do file.
`$sValue` is a value of checkbox `ON` is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i had really understood your question, is this the answer:

`$sValue` is an array, too. This array represent `$sVideo['2']`.
That mean you must loop through this array to get the value of `$sVideo['3']`

i have tested with this little script:

```
//this is array is like your film request
$aKatalogi = array("usun" => array("sVideo2" => array("this is my value")));


if (is_array($aKatalogi['usun'])) {
     //loop throug the films
    foreach ($aKatalogi['usun'] as $iKlucz => $sVideo2Value) {

        if(is_array($sVideo2Value) ){
             //loop throug the sVideo2
            foreach ($sVideo2Value as $sVideo3Key => $sVideo3Value) {
                echo $sVideo3Value;
            }
        }

    }
}
```